# unable to understand use of scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, function, mediapipe

```
::mediapipe::Status RunMPPGraph() {
  std::string calculator_graph_config_contents;
  MP_RETURN_IF_ERROR(mediapipe::file::GetContents(
      FLAGS_calculator_graph_config_file, &calculator_graph_config_contents));
  LOG(INFO) << "Get calculator graph config contents: "
            << calculator_graph_config_contents;
  mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig config =
      mediapipe::ParseTextProtoOrDie<mediapipe::CalculatorGraphConfig>(
          calculator_graph_config_contents);
```

This is a small section of a larger code offered by Google's [Mediapipe](https://github.com/google/mediapipe), which uses the scope resolution operator to define `RunMPPGraph()`. I don't understand anything about this definition. Can someone tell me what is going on?

This looks like a function and I'm pretty sure it is: `::mediapipe::Status RunMPPGraph()` ... but the basic way to define a function is ---> `ReturnType FunctionName(parameters)`, and in this program `RunMPPGraph` is the name, so that means `::mediapipe::Status` is the return type. In the main function, `RunMPPGraph`() is called with this statement ---> `::mediapipe::Status run_status = RunMPPGraph();` so that means `::mediapipe::Status` is some form of user defined data type. So I wanted to know if we can break down `::mediapipe::Status` into more smaller parts ?

Comment: @JeJo the part " ::mediapipe::Status RunMPPGraph() " . This looks like a function and I'm pretty sure it is, but the basic way to define a function is ---> " ReturnType FunctionName ( parameters ) ", and in this program --->  RunMPPGraph() is the name, so that means ::mediapipe::Status is the return type. In the main function, RunMPPGraph() is called with this statement ---> "  ::mediapipe::Status run_status = RunMPPGraph();   " so that means ::mediapipe::Status is some form of user defined data type. So I wanted to know if we can break down ::mediapipe::Status into more smaller parts ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straigtforward, I guess you're not familiar with namespaces.

```
::mediapipe::Status RunMPPGraph()
```

`RnuMMPGraph` is a function taking zero arguments and returning `::mediapipe::Status`. `Status` is a type defined in the `mediapipe` namespace which is defined in the global namespace.

Answer (score 7):

The  resolution operator in C++ is used in different ways:

1-Access to class inside another class:

```
 class A
 {
    ...
    class B
    {
        static int var;
    }
 }
 int x =A::B::var.
```

2- Access to a global variable when there is a local variable with same name.

```
int gval = 5;
{
    int gval = 10;
    int y = ::gval;//the value assign for y is 5
}
```

3- TO access to a static variable inside a class.

```
 class A
 {
    static int x;
 };
 int y = A::x;
```

4- When using from multiple inheritance.

```
class A
{
   protected:
     int l;
}
class B
{
   protected:
     int l;
}
class c: class A, class B
{
   public:
    int f()
    {
       int c1 = A::l;
       int c2 = B::l;
    }
}
```

5- For namespace.

Your case satisfy in Item 2.